# Facebook Marketing API - user_role

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

```
me/adaccounts?fields=user_role
```

What is the meaning of user_role? Is there a list of ID meanings?

Answer (score -1):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/aduser/v2.7#fields:

> **role**
>
> The role the user has on the account.
>
> 1001 = Administrator access
>      1002 = Advertiser (ad manager) access
>      1003 = Analyst access
>      1004 = Direct sales access (For a small number of directly managed accounts)

Comment: OP asked for adaccount's field, not aduser's

Comment: @Nakilon and what do you think _The role the user has on the account_ means ...?

Answer (score -1):

The `user_role` field is not a usable/useful field, I've filed to have it removed from the API.

More detail - as noted in other questions, the id returned does not conform to the role IDs (in the previous answer).

TL;DR - It's legacy code that will get removed.